# How to refresh navigation pane using VBA

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a front end database, and I dynamically add some linked tables to the back end database. Next, I'm reading their IDs from the hidden system tables in order to add them to the navigation pane, in some custom groups I have created.

While I believe I'm using the correct tables / values, I can't find any way to refresh the navigation pane after I'm finished with the inserts in MSysNavPaneGroupToObjects table.

The only information for something close to what I'm trying to achieve can be found here: [Change Navigation pane group in access through vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27366038/change-navigation-pane-group-in-access-through-vba)

But in my case, all values are being created successfully (I think), but I can't see the entries in the navigation pane. Sometimes it works, but most of the times I only see empty groups.

I wonder if anyone has solve something similar or there is a documentation/forum I can find more information. Thanks

Comment: Once you've added the values to the table(s) do the new entries show up if you click on the Navigation Pane and hit [F5]? Do they appear if you close and re-open the database?

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately no they don't, either by pressing F5 or by closing and opening the database.

Comment: Are you only adding the linked tables when you first open the front-end, or is it something that can it happen any time after?

Comment: I'm using a form to select the destination database. When I select the destination database, I drop the previous linked tables then re-create the linked tables. I only have a normal path to the database like "C:\path\to\database.accdb". Then I make a query to find the IDs of the new linked tables and I insert a new row to the SysNavPaneGroupToObjects table, having object ID the ID of the linked table, and group id the id of the group I've already added. Since it's working sometimes, and my 6 tables split to two diffrent groups, I believe this is somewhat correct.

Comment: *"Sometimes it works, but most of the times I only see empty groups."* - Further to Wayne's code comment in his [answer to the other question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27389179/2144390) where he says "This [MSysNavPaneObjectIDs] table gets rebuilt at the whim of Access" ... Could you try running the code (that updates the MSysNavPane* tables) from another application, e.g., another Access database, a VBScript, or whatever, *while the database being updated is **not** open in MSACCESS.EXE* to see if the results are more consistent?

Comment: I will give it a try tomorrow. I tested the 2 answers in this question but they don't work. So now I'm thinking it might not have to do with refreshing the navigation pane, but maybe there is a pattern in the MSysNavPane* tables that "blocks" it from updating properly. I will try to manually drag and drop some tables and see if I can recognize it and replicate the correct behaviour.

Answer (score 6):

Try the following [method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa221557%28v=office.11%29.aspx):

```
Application.RefreshDatabaseWindow
```

Alternatively:

```
CurrentDb.TableDefs.Refresh
```

Comment: Thanks, I will have to try that on Monday, since I don't have ms-access at home. I will let you know if it works

Comment: I did try your suggestion but it didn't make any difference, so I think there is a conflict between ms-access updating the tables and my code updating the tables at the same time. I will update the question or provide an answer when I finally resolve this. Thanks for your time anyway.

Answer (score 1):

There was a bug in access where you had to refresh the nav pane for them to show up or even close and re-open.

Another option is to hide then show but that's probably just refreshing it like the other suggestion

---

**Hide**

```
DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdWindowHide
```

**Show**

```
DoCmd.SelectObject acTable, , True
```

Comment: I did try your suggestion but it didn't make any difference, so I think there is a conflict between ms-access updating the tables and my code updating the tables at the same time. I will update the question or provide an answer when I finally resolve this. Thanks for your time anyway.

Answer (score 1):

If the changes written to the `MSysNav*` tables do not always appear in the Navigation Pane itself, even after closing and re-opening the database, then this is not really a "refresh" issue. Something else might be interfering with the updates to those tables, rendering your changes ineffective.

In an [answer to a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27389179/2144390) Wayne G. Dunn suggests that "This [MSysNavPaneObjectIDs] table gets rebuilt at the whim of Access", which could conceivably conflict with updates to that table from an application's VBA code. If that is true and MSACCESS.EXE expects (effectively) exclusive access to the `MSysNav*` system tables while it has a database open, then a workaround would be to ensure that the database being modified is *not* open in MSACCESS.EXE when the `MSysNav*` modifications are being applied.

One way to do that would be to use VBA code in the "main" database to

1. write the pertinent details to a temporary text file
2. launch a separate process that will perform the updates, and then immediately
3. close the "main" database using `Application.Quit`.

The separate process could be running code in another Access database, a VBScript, or whatever you prefer. It would

1. read the pertinent details from the temporary text file,
2. update the `MSysNav*` tables in the main database while MSACCESS.EXE does not have it open,
3. delete the temporary text file,
4. re-launch MSACCESS.EXE with the main database, and then
5. terminate itself.

The "pertinent details" to be shared between the two processes would depend on the implementation details of this approach, but would likely include

- the full path to the "main" database (so the separate process can find it),
- the full path to the relevant copy of MSACCESS.EXE (so the separate process can re-load the main database when it is finished), and
- the item(s) to be added or updated in the `MSysNav*` tables of the main database.

Comment: Unfortunately I didn't have time to thoroughly test any of these suggestions this week, and I just realized I have to award the bounty to someone soon. It was a bad choice to start this question between holidays :) So I will award the bounty to this answer, because I have a feeling it is not a refreshing issue after all, and I will edit / update the question as soon as I understand what is causing this problem. Thanks for your suggestions Gord.