# Can VBA be used to change the sort order of the Microsoft Access Navigation Pane..?

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007

Does the Microsoft Access 2007 Navigation Pane have a simple `.Sort` property that can be accessed by VBA..?

I would like to add some AutoExec code to a database which explicitly sets the NavPane to sort by name each time a user opens it.

I understand changing the NavPane system tables is a big can of worms, but I was wondering if something as simple as the sorting could be changed through an object property somewhere.

Comment: Cant you just make a Query that sorts it by name each time the query opens?

Comment: None that I am aware of. But really, users should not be interacting with Navigation Pane anyway.

Comment: Brax, I don't understand your question. Does the NavPane have a query behind it somewhere..?

Comment: June7, I agree. That's why I'd like to develop a way for it to always be sorted by name when a user opens the db. =-)

Comment: Perhaps look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27366038/change-navigation-pane-group-in-access-through-vba.  No, it's not a "simple .Sort" property, but that would imply some object model for the Nav Pane which also doesn't exist.

Comment: C Perkins, thank you that's got some good reading. I'm aware of some of it at various levels, was even thinking of starting a NavPane blog. I've seen some interesting things happen in the NavPane tables as I've developed this database. But I have yet to find a really good discussion page focused only on the NavPane.

Answer (score 0):

MS has an alternative approach which could basically be described as "roll your own replacement navigation page". Links to their information are on https://support.office.com/en-us/article/customize-the-navigation-pane-ccfb0ee7-d72f-4923-b4fb-ed6c15484244. I have not yet tried to follow their instructions, so I cannot report on how easy, difficult or effective this is.

Comment: Ahh thanks, I'm already heavily into that. My main "workbench" db has about 70 custom groups for the many projects I work on with this jigundious SQL server I'm attached to. I got all excited, when I saw "roll you own", I thought it was going to explain how to code a custom fly-out listbox or something. =-)